# Rhino Mocks - Mock a method call to Service inside a property

Tags: unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I am trying to test that the property gets it's value from the return of a Service call, but I am having trouble mocking the service call.

Here is my property:

```
    public ICountry Country
    {
        get
        {
            if (_country == null)
            {
                ICountryService countryService = new CountryService();
                _country = countryService.GetCountryForCountryId(_address.CountryId);
            }
            return _country;
        }
    }
```

Here is my attempt at testing this:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Country_should_return_Country_from_CountryService()
    {
        const string countryId = "US";
        _address.CountryId = countryId;

        var address = MockRepository.GenerateStub<Address>(_address);

        var country = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ICountry>();
        var countryService = MockRepository.GenerateStub<ICountryService>();

        countryService.Stub(x => x.GetCountryForCountryId(countryId)).IgnoreArguments().Return(country);

        Assert.AreEqual(address.Country, country);
    }
```

I keep getting an error because the real countryService is being called, not my mock. I am using MsTest and Rhino Mocks.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You problem is that the property is directly constructing the dependency. Due to this the mock service is not getting called, the actual real CountryService implementation is getting called.

A way around this might be to utilize constructor injection of a CountryService factory (or the service itself) in the other objects (Address?) constructor. This way you could get your fake CountryService (the mock) to be returned and be the one called by the method

For example:

```
private ICountryService _countryService;

//constructor
public OuterObject(ICountryService countryService)
{
    //maybe guard clause
    _countryService = countryService;
}


public ICountry Country
{
    get
    {
        if (_country == null)
        {
            _country = _countryService.GetCountryForCountryId(_address.CountryId);
        }
        return _country;
    }
}
```

You would need to then pass the mocked ICountryService into the other objects constructor in your unit test

Comment: Problem with that is that I also am calling a State service to get the IState property, and there could be others.  I didn't want to rely on passing these objects into the class just to get the object.

Comment: What you could then do is utilize an ObjectFactory class that will let you do - objectFactory.GetInstance<ICountryService>() OR objectFactory.GetInstance<IStateService>()... This way you only have one dependency to inject into the class - internally the ObjectFactory could utilize an IOC container or whatever mechanism you'd like to construct it's objects, just as long as it allows you to swap those dependencies out for your Unit tests